# Flutter navigation from popup menu item

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter and struggling to do some changes in my code.. When I click **settings** in Popup menu I want to navigate to **CreateProfile()** page.. I try to add **'on Tap**' but it is not working. how should I do this properly.. appreciate your help on this.. below  my code shows how I was try to do the above task.

> HomeScreen.dart

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:image_uploader/Pages/ChatPage.dart';
    import 'package:image_uploader/Profile/CreateProfile.dart';
    
    
    class Homescreen extends StatefulWidget {
      Homescreen({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);
    
    
      @override
      _HomescreenState createState() => _HomescreenState();
    }
    
    class _HomescreenState extends State<Homescreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{
    
      late final TabController _controller;
    
    @override
    void initState(){
    
      _controller =TabController(length: 4, vsync:this, initialIndex: 0);
      super.initState();
    }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Whatsapp Clone"),
            actions: [
              IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search), onPressed: () {}),
              PopupMenuButton<String>(
                onSelected: (value) {
                  print(value);
                },
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext contesxt) {
                  return [
                    PopupMenuItem(
                      child: Text("New group"),
                      value: "New group",
                    ),
                    PopupMenuItem(
                      child: Text("New broadcast"),
                      value: "New broadcast",
                    ),
                    PopupMenuItem(
                      child: Text("Whatsapp Web"),
                      value: "Whatsapp Web",
                    ),
                    PopupMenuItem(
                      child: Text("Starred messages"),
                      value: "Starred messages",
                    ),
//when I click this settings I want to navifate to createprofile page
                    PopupMenuItem(
                      child: Text("Settings",),
                      value: "Settings",
                      onTap: () => {
                        Navigator.push(context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CreateProfile(
                                key: UniqueKey()))),
    
                      },
                    ),
                  ];
                },
              )
            ],
            bottom: TabBar(
              controller:_controller,
              indicatorColor: Colors.white,
              tabs:[
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),),
                Tab(text: "CHATS",),
                Tab(text: "STATUS",),
                Tab(text: "CALLS",),
    
              ]
            ),
        ),
          body: TabBarView(
            controller: _controller,
            children: [
    
              Text("Camera"),
              ChatPage(),
              Text("Status"),
              Text("Calls"),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your PopupMenuButton:

```
onSelected: (result) {
    if (result == 0) {
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SettingPage()),
        );
    }
},
```

And change your setting button to:

```
PopupMenuItem(
    child: Text("Settings"),
    value: 0,
),
```

add this to each popupmenuitem, obviously the first one will be 0...1..etc